# Why won't hover work with moving objects?

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit, hover

I am making a solar system in CSS, and here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kAKdm/.

However, it seems that `:hover` will only work with the sun which is the only item which does not move with CSS animations.

Does anyone know a way to make the `:hover` work with the planets also? I want to do something like this, but it will of course be overridden by the animation:

```
#planets > div:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be clear, `:hover` works perfectly. If you implement `#planets > div:hover { background: orange !important; }` you'll find the background of any planet does become orange when you hover. What doesn't work is a second `-webkit-transform` when there's already one in effect (and constantly changing) due to the animation.

Comment: The problem must be in -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); since if you try changing some other property the :hover works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicaly if you are scaling the planets you are changing it's `width, height, top, left, border-radius` properties.

scale sure is handy but since you override the transform you could try this:

```
#planet-venus:hover {
width:20px;
height:20px;
left: 396px;
top: 290px; 
border-radius:10px;
}
```

You will have to calculate the width height and reposition each planet by half the ammount of scale but it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/kAKdm/21/ - try hover venus.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't accept `div:hover`, it only accepts `img:hover`. So instead of `#planets > div:hover`, use:

```
#planets > div img:hover
```

For more details visit: http://dinolatoga.com/2009/09/18/amazing-imag-hover-effects-with-webkit-and-css/